# Using the A* search algorithm to solve Theseus and the Minotaur puzzles

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, search

I recently watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umszOeerdsU) which used the BFS search algorithm to solve a Theseus and the Minotaur puzzle. If you are not familiar with it, it is a puzzle where Theseus and the Minotaur are put in a tiled maze, and Theseus must get to the escape without getting caught by the Minotaur. Every time Theseus moves one tile, the Minotaur moves twice. However, the behaviour of the Minotaur is such that it can only move directly towards Theseus, and it will always try to move horizontally before trying to move vertically. Thus, this can be exploited in order to escape the maze. A nice implementation of the game can be found [here](https://estivalet.github.io/theseus-minotaur/) if you are interested in trying to play it.

I am now attempting to implement [my own solver](https://github.com/ang9009/minotaur/settings/set_visibility) in Kotlin, but using the A* algorithm instead of BFS. However, I am having trouble doing so, and I'm not sure why my code doesn't work. Instead of traditional A* algorithms where there is a node object that stores the position of the agent, i have a state object that stores the positions of Theseus and the Minotaur. I then use a series of helper functions to determine the next possible positions of Theseus and the Minotaur such that Theseus does not run into walls, out of a maze, or into the Minotaur (the function getNextStates). From there, I use a quite traditional implementation of the A* algorithm that only considers the position of Theseus (the function aStar), and uses a helper function to calculate the heuristic based on Theseus' position from the goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the bugs that I see.

1. Theseus can't wait in your solver. It is valid for him to stand in place. That is, you need the move `0 to 0`.
2. The minotaur can catch Theseus at the goal in your solver. But in the game, Theseus wins if he gets to the goal, even if the Minotaur can catch up. So in `getNextStates`, don't lose the state where the Minotaur catches Theseus at the goal.
3. You're missing walls. The game has walls that the minotaur and Theseus can't go through. You need a representation that lets you notice that you don't just need legal start and end positions, you also need to have not moved through a wall.
4. Your `gScore` needs to be the score of the state, not the score of where Theseus is. The winning path in your game is `lddrdduuluuuuurrrrr`. (l = left, r = right, u = up, d = down, w = wait) Theseus needs to be allowed to retrace his path after trapping the minotaur. That's not a repeated position, because it matters that the minotaur has been trapped.

Comment: Your comment about the backtracking saved me!! I was using Theseus' position for the key, which doesn't allow him to go back since that doesn't consider the Minotaur's position. I fixed it by using "current" as the gScore key instead of current.theseusPos. Thanks :)